# Shutdown a jupyter notebook from said notebook

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I work in jupyter notebooks running on a server. I often let my heavy duty code run overnight. I'd like to free the server memory when my code is finished so other people can work in the morning. I was thinking about putting some code to free the memory / shut the notebook in the last chunk.

How would I achieve that ? Do you see another more relevant course of action ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [github discussion](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/1880) following solution was proposed:

```
%%javascript
require(
    ["base/js/dialog"], 
    function(dialog) {
        dialog.modal({

                title: 'Notebook Halted',
                body: 'This notebook is no longer running; the kernel has been halted. Close the browser tab, or, to continue working, restart the kernel.',
                buttons: {
                    'Kernel restart': { click: function(){ Jupyter.notebook.session.restart(); } }
                }
        });
    }
);
Jupyter.notebook.session.delete();
```

Comment: Thanks, from another discussion, i appears that only the first and last lines are needed.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that :

```
%%javascript
Jupyter.notebook.session.delete();
```

Is enough to achieve the desired shutdown.

The code proposed by Alexandra Dudkina seems to also open a dialog box that offer to restart the kernel. which is unnecessary in my usecase.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to programmatically **stop** your **Google Colab** runtime, use this:

```py
from google.colab import runtime
runtime.unassign()
```